# Sending data to service array brute force

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, if-statement, ejs

**I can't find an answer to my question, can you help me friends**
*what kind of requests, I get: `facebook, linkedin, reddit`*
*I don't want to write a lot of code, so I want to ask you how I can make*
*How do I create a check loop, and send the data (the data is the same for all services)*
*to go through and find the right service. send the right service and data. Again, the data for all services is the same*
*as you can see, I write a lot of conditional statements, and I don't like it, I want to put
*I use ejs, express*

*I just want to get rid of a lot of code..*

everything into one loop and work*

```
    var servies = ["facebook", "linkedin", "reddit"]

    servies.forEach(service => {
        console.log(service);
    });

    if (service == "linkedin") {
        res.render('linkedin', {
            id: xssFilters(id),
            name: xssFilters(name),
            image: xssFilters(photo),
            firstName: xssFilters(firstName),
        })
    }
    if (service == "reddit") {
        res.render('reddit', {
            id: xssFilters(id),
            name: xssFilters(name),
            image: xssFilters(photo),
            firstName: xssFilters(firstName),
        })
    }


    if (service == "facebook") {
        res.render('facebook', {
            id: xssFilters(id),
            name: xssFilters(name),
            image: xssFilters(photo),
            firstName: xssFilters(firstName),
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
 var servies = ["facebook", "linkedin", "reddit"]

    servies.forEach(service => {
        console.log(service);

        res.render(service, {
            id: xssFilters(id),
            name: xssFilters(name),
            image: xssFilters(photo),
            firstName: xssFilters(firstName),
        })


    });
```

since in your example code, you don't do anything different between the different services, but only replace the string name of the service, and you already have a loop for that.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you elaborate? does the `res.render` not get called, is the behavior wrong, or is the data sent wrong?

Comment: ahahaha, I'm working)) I posted a ready answer to my own question, Sorry.Thanks XDD